# Wouldn't there be a point to add a bookmark option for answers?

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmark

We have all seen interesting answers now and then. Sometimes the question is nothing special but one or more answers to the same question are very interesting.

There is already a way to star questions. You can star this post for example.

But say someone posts an answer you find not only answers the question, but also adds some interesting thoughts to one of your projects. Then you would naturally want to bookmark it.

So, wouldn't it be useful to be able to bookmark an answer? I would certainly like it.

Comment: I don't see why there should be more than one way of marking questions directly on SO... Post does not explain why favorite is not enough either...

Comment: You should add the detail *"I'm using the app a lot."* to your question, it kinda makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a browser to visit Stack Overflow. That means you can grab a link to the answer (with the share option underneath it), like this one:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327647/4751173

and add it as a bookmark in your browser.

Comment: I'm using the app a lot. It would be practical to have a function to be able to store them in the Stack acount.

Comment: Well, there must be some way you could have mentioned that in your question? There's probably even a tag as well.