# Bookmark a specific answer (or comment)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

Sometimes it would be useful to bookmark a specific answer or comment. Example: I have no need for the question or answers, but a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma/54873916?noredirect=1#comment113510410_54873916) would be great to bookmark. If I bookmark the question, future me might have no idea why I did so, and overlook the comment.

An auxiliary benefit could also be to make it easier to search through bookmarks (since they could be narrowed down a little by question/answer/comment)

Comment: I'm still holding out for this feature at some point in the future. It'd be really nice, for all the reasons outlined across the [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400843/11047824) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327646/11047824) [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/776523) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569/776523) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7671/776523) [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125866/776523).